# Conversion issues with VARCHAR to DATE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have sample data like this :

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), CONVERT(DATE, '11/10/1997', 3), 120);
```

when i execute this I'm getting Error like this :

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

So then i have removed first 2 characters of year 1997

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), CONVERT(DATE, '11/10/97', 3), 120);
```

And it gave Result Set like this :

```
Date
1997-10-11
```

So it got converted from  DD/MM/YY Format to YYYY-MM-DD

Fine But why it has taken 1997 if I'm going to give 17 it will give as 2017.
If i give 37 it will give 2037 and if i give 67 and it is giving 1967 .

And lastly how can DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-DD Format

Comment: think of a SQL DATE datatype as not having an actual format of DD/MM/YY or YYYY/MM/DD - because that format is only something used to display it to you as a string.  The year conundrum is due to 'zoning' simply deciding that 97 is more likely to be 1997 than 1897 or 2097 (justified?  you decide)  I think you need to find a different conversion format value than 120

Comment: [Configure the two digit year cutoff Server Configuration Option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191004.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `103` when you specify four digit year:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '11/10/1997', 103)
-- 1997-10-11 (DATE)
```

If you want to convert the date back to a string, convert it again:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATE, '11/10/1997', 103), 120)
-- 1997-10-11 (VARCHAR)
```

Complete list of *styles* [is available here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: but why it is predicting the years if i give 37 it is returning back 2037 if i give 50 it is giving 1950 @salman

Comment: Two digit years such as 50 and 37 are ambiguous. SQL server uses a [configuration option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191004(v=sql.110).aspx) to decide if 37 should be 1937 or 2037. By default, values `0...49` belong to 2000s and 50...99 belong to 1900s. You can configure this but the correct solution is to use four digit  years.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 3 you can pun 103.
So : 
`SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(19), CONVERT(DATE, '11/10/1997', 103), 120);` will return 1997-10-11

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
declare @datechar as char(19) ='11/10/1997'

select FORMAT(convert(date,@datechar,103),'yyyy-MM-dd')
```